# Cannot SYNC Google Chromium source files

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, chromium

I've been trying to download the source for the Chromium OS to check it out, but I keep getting issues with GIT repositories, apparently. I followed the instructions provided by Google, but I still have trouble. Here's what I see using REPO from the depot_tools download:

```
root@Ubuntu1204:/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos# repo sync
Fetching projects:   8% (12/147)  remote: Counting objects: 7, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
From https://git.chromium.org/git/chromiumos/overlays/board-overlays
   ece0843..99b4022f master     -> cros/master
Fetching projects:  77% (114/147)  fatal: Not a git repository: '/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos/.repo/projects/src/third_party/ltp.git'
Fetching projects:  78% (115/147)  fatal: Not a git repository: '/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos/.repo/projects/src/third_party/marvell.git'
Fetching projects:  79% (117/147)  fatal: Not a git repository: '/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos/.repo/projects/src/third_party/memtest.git'
fatal: Not a git repository: '/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos/.repo/projects/src/third_party/mesa.git'
Fetching projects:  80% (118/147)  fatal: Not a git repository: '/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos/.repo/projects/src/third_party/miniFakeDns.git'
fatal: Not a git repository: '/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos/.repo/projects/src/third_party/mobile-broadband-provider-info.git'
Fetching projects:  81% (120/147)  fatal: Not a git repository: '/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos/.repo/projects/src/third_party/modemmanager-next.git'
Fetching projects:  95% (140/147)  fatal: Not a git repository: '/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos/.repo/projects/src/third_party/mesa.git'
fatal: Not a git repository: '/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos/.repo/projects/src/third_party/memtest.git'
fatal: Not a git repository: '/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos/.repo/projects/src/third_party/ltp.git'
fatal: Not a git repository: '/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos/.repo/projects/src/third_party/miniFakeDns.git'
fatal: Not a git repository: '/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos/.repo/projects/src/third_party/modemmanager-next.git'
fatal: Not a git repository: '/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos/.repo/projects/src/third_party/mobile-broadband-provider-info.git'
fatal: Not a git repository: '/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos/.repo/projects/src/third_party/marvell.git'
error: Cannot fetch chromiumos/third_party/mesa
error: Cannot fetch chromiumos/third_party/modemmanager-next
error: Cannot fetch chromiumos/third_party/ltp
error: Cannot fetch chromiumos/third_party/minifakedns
error: Cannot fetch chromiumos/third_party/memtest
error: Cannot fetch chromiumos/third_party/marvell
error: Cannot fetch chromiumos/third_party/mobile-broadband-provider-info

error: Exited sync due to fetch errors
```

This is copied directly from the terminal. I've checked the data, it all appears to be there, it downloaded, but for the life of me I don't understand what I'm missing. If there's any further information that would help, let me know.

Also, git is installed, so I know that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to skip the part with 
/usr/local/path/to/source/chromiumos/ from crappy instructions.

Use /home/$USER/chromiumos/

Then after 5 hours.

```
cd  ~/chromiumos
./chromite/bin/cros_sdk
```

then you  should land in src then:

```
export BOARD=panda
./setup_board --board=${BOARD}
./set_shared_user_password.sh
./build_packages --board=${BOARD}
# go camping... :)
./build_image --board=${BOARD} --noenable_rootfs_verification dev
cd ~/trunk/src/build/images/${BOARD}/latest
```